# How to retrieve specific lines of text using Tesseract in C++?

Tags: c++, tesseract, leptonica

I'm trying to build a project that uses tesseract to pull the title of a Magic card from an image. Currently I've got the first example from https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Examples_C++.html to work, but the example that I'm actually interested in GetComponentImages_example does not work.

I'm getting the error that pointer to incomplete class type "Box" and "Boxa" is not allowed. I've installed both leptonica and Tesseract through vcpkg, and the folder with the libraries is included in additional library directories for the project. I've tried creating new projects as well as reinstalling both tesseract and leptonica

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There was a change in Leptonica that hid some internal structures. Include the correct leptonica headers and examples will work.

Comment: I'm including the leptonica/allheaders.h file, is there another header file that I should be using?